# Hovering over one element animates another

Tags: css, html

I learned here on Stack Overflow that I can hover over first element and animate second one as long as second one sits behind inside first one in HTML5.

So I have an example of this:

```
div.oblacek-hold:hover img.oblacek {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px) opacity(100%);
    -o-filter: blur(0px) opacity(100%);
    -ms-filter: blur(0px) opacity(100%);
    filter: blur(0px) opacity(100%);
}
```

Here `img.oblacek` sits inside `div.oblacek-hold` element and when a mouse hovers over `div.oblacek-hold`, `img.oblacek` is animated. This works great! but `img.oblacek` is also animated if I hover `img.oblacek` and this is what I don't want.

Is there any way of solving this using CSS?

Comment: Please give a fiddle demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give value as default with `!important` in `img.oblacek`.

Something like this

```
.oblacek:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px) opacity(100%) !important;
    -o-filter: blur(0px) opacity(100%) !important;
    -ms-filter: blur(0px) opacity(100%) !important;
    filter: blur(0px) opacity(100%) !important;
}
```

Check sample fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/h9vjezvp/1/

Comment: This works for me. Thank you. Could you explain why is important needed here?

Comment: welcome, When the !important keyword is used on a specific property/value pair, it will cause that particular value to escape the cascade and become, as the name suggests, the most important value for that property, overriding any others.check the article here https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `:hover` to `img.oblacek` and override unwanted properties with `!important` like

```
img.oblacek:hover {
    filter: blur(0px) opacity(100%) !important;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/4hh3c0jo/)

Comment: I added your piece of code in CSS and it doesn't work. Could you explain a bit more...

Comment: Use proper inheritance!! https://jsfiddle.net/4hh3c0jo/1/
NEVER EVER use `!important` unless you are styling HTML emails

Comment: @Christophe fair, my bad